# Other similar apps don't do Permission controls

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am developing a camera app for android, and this app obviously require the Camera permission to work.

I have an Android 6 smartphone and I have just noticed that other similar apps don't show the permission request dialog but in Settings->Applications, I see that the permission is already granted for these apps. How is this possible ? Maybe because these are old apps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is this possible ?

Their `targetSdkVersion` is below 23.

Comment: So could I use a targetSdkVersion below 23 too ? Or there are disadvantages ?

Comment: @xRobot: "Or there are disadvantages ?" -- users will experience various effects due to your lower `targetSdkVersion`. If it is below 23, they will be forced to agree to all permissions at install time, and some may elect to skip your app as a result. If it is below 24, your app will display a "may not be compatible with split-screen" message if the user uses Android 7.0 multi-window. And so on.